# Switch tabs in Debian installer over serial console with PuTTy

Tags: debian, keyboard-shortcuts, serial-port, debian-installer, putty

I'm currently trying to install Debian on a system with no video output. All I have is serial console.
I know how to get it started and all, and even made it install automatically with a preseeded config. The installation itself is absolutely no issue.

Now what I haven't figured out is how I can switch between the different tabs the installer has:

[image: Screenshot]

I'd love to have that so I can switch to the log and follow the installation in much more detail for debugging purposes (the installation itself runs fully automatically).

I already tried

- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>-<kbd>4</kbd>
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F4</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>-<kbd>4</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F4</kbd>

Though none of those worked. It might very well be that one of those is the correct shortcut, but PuTTy is not sending them because either PuTTy or Windows itself is handling it (Like <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like the Debian installer might use the well-known `screen` utility to implement multiple tabs on a serial console, so use its key combinations to switch tabs:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, then <kbd>1</kbd>-<kbd>4</kbd>

An alternative tool for the same purpose is `tmux`, which might be newer than `screen`... but apparently `screen` is a GNU project and `tmux` might be BSD. I would guess that `screen` is still the more widespread one. Debian is likely to prefer GNU software anyway.

Some other distribution might use `tmux` instead, and its basic key combinations are very similar to `screen`'s, but the prefix key combination is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.

Comment: Ctrl + A, then 1-4 did work!

Comment: So the installer either uses `screen` to implement the "tabs" on a serial console, or reuses its key combinations since they are expected to be reasonably familiar to serious terminal users. Makes sense.

Comment: Might be a good idea to add a small appendum to your answer, pointing out that it's Ctrl + A and not Ctrl + B.

Comment: Just as easy to rewrite the whole answer to take out the ambiguity, while leaving information on the tmux keystrokes too, in case it helps someone with a similar problem on a different distribution.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @telcoM answer:

For those running the Debian installer through `screen` itself, like a UART connection to some monitor-less device, you can't use <kbd>Ctrl+a</kbd> directly. That would be picked up by your local `screen` instance.

Instead, you need to perform <kbd>Ctrl+a</kbd> then <kbd>a</kbd> first to send <kbd>Ctrl+a</kbd> to the installer, followed by the number.

So <kbd>Ctrl+a</kbd>, then <kbd>a</kbd>, then <kbd>1</kbd>-<kbd>4</kbd>.

Comment: Awesome! I was struggling with exactly this issue. Thanks!

Comment: I ran into the same issue, but with `minicom` - I had to use Ctrl+a Ctrl+a and _then_ 1 - 4 to get the proper sequence of escapes and literal keys. Yeesh!